# Continuity & boundedness on open interval implies uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous and bounded on $(0,1)$. Is $f(x)$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?

I think yes, because it's bounded, i.e. there exists $M: |f(x)| < M$. We could use this M as $\delta$ in the definition of uniformly continuous function for any $\epsilon$. My textbook says, the answer is no. Why?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Mitra for counterexample. I confused delta and epsilon in the definition!

Comment: @DavidMitra: I think your comment should be made an answer.

Answer (score 6):

As David Mitra's comment suggests, $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ over the interval $(0,1)$ is an excellent example of a function that is bounded, continuous, but not uniformly continuous. To see why, note that
$$
a_n =  \frac{1}{\pi n+ \pi/2}
$$
satisfies $a_n \to 0$ but $f(a_n) = (-1)^n$.

Perhaps this will help your intuition: if $f$ is differentiable on an open interval, then it will be uniformly continuous so long as *its derivative*, $f'$, is bounded.